# Server CPU percentage goes very high when running complicated SQLs

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am a web designer by trade so apologies for any lack of knowledge and appreciate any references that can be provided.

Here is the situation, our company has a collection of webapps that we use in house, built with PHP & MySQL. We had them hosted on a hostgator dedicated server (4 Cores 4GB RAM).

Recently, management wanted to move the servers closer to home (UK) and we decided to get a Heart Internet [Hybrid Server](http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/hybrid-servers/) (12 Cores & 28GB RAM).

Transfer has been completed and we can definitely see a massive improvement on speed for static pages and simply Query pages.

However, whenever attempting to access a page which iterates a large number of records (anything from 10,000+) the page just loads and loads.... and in WHM we can see under the 'Current Processes' the server CPU spirals out of control, starting in the low 20% and increasing all the way up until 200%+!

I know that the queries weren't designed brilliantly (inner selects used badly etc) I have attempted to rectify this in some cases with better index usage and in some cases this has improved performance. But, as the webapps are so large, it would take too long to rewrite the bad SQLs and improve the performance that way.

I suspect that this is more likely a server misconfiguration, as the queries did work on our previous server, but were just a little slow. Another possible cause of this is some sort of cache that was built up on the previous server but is not on the new server so would naturally take some time to 'create'.

Below is an example of one of the queries that is hanging on the new server but didn't hang on the old server (just took about 4/5 seconds).

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_number, o.customer_id, o.order_date, CONCAT( cd.customer_fname,  ' ', customer_lname ) AS CustomerName, (

SELECT status_id
FROM Order_Tracking
WHERE order_id = o.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
)CurrState
FROM Orders o, Customer_Details cd
WHERE o.customer_id = cd.id
AND (

SELECT status_id
FROM Order_Tracking
WHERE order_id = o.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
) =1
ORDER BY o.order_number
```

Below is a screenshot of the CPU usage 5 minutes after browsing to a page as described above.

[image: High CPU Usage]

Comment: Does your MySQL server software have enough RAM available to it?  This sounds like it's thrashing.  When it's doing this say `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to ask it what exactly it's working on.  See here for some more tips.  http://serverfault.com/questions/42789/how-to-increase-memory-usage-in-mysql-server-to-improve-speed   Hostgator happens to be very skillful at configuring MySQL.

Comment: Hi Ollie, that's the query I am running to see what is running at the time of page load. The only query running at the time is the one related to the pageload (I am the only one using system). Another example query posted below, but can't see how it could be a SQL query fault if they were working okay (albeit slowly) on the hostgator server. Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you consider modifying the PHP code? Would you consider improving the query? And would you consider adding some indexes?

Comment: Issue this command on both your HostGator and self-built server: `SHOW VARIABLES`  Then line up the results side by side and see if you can figure out what's different. I suspect you'll find lots of differences, and at least one or two will relate to RAM or sort space allocation. Try changing the variables on your local server.  You'll have to learn about MySQL Database Administration to get this right. You might consider posting a followup question at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ when you have this information in hand.

Comment: Also, were your web apps and MySQL server software running on the same server instance at HostGator? Are they running on the same server instance in house? Is your in-house MySQL server software running on a virtual machine on your fancy new server system?  Is that virtual machine provisioned with enough RAM and high-speed disk channels for a DBMS? Have your tables been optimized  and indexes rebuilt since you migrated your data?  Sometimes it takes a while to get things tuned up after migration. Be aware that people on Stack Overflow tend to look for programming solutions to all problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are using DESC ordering, indexing for which is not supported by MySQL, ever in v.5.6.

[13.1.11. CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)

And it seems that heavy DISTINCT operation needs a temporary table.

[8.13.15. DISTINCT Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/distinct-optimization.html)

So this is rather query and schema optimization problem which is not related to the server configuration.

So query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  Orders.order_number,
  Orders.customer_id,
  Orders.order_date,
  CONCAT(Customer_Details.customer_fname,  ' ', Customer_Details.customer_lname) AS CustomerName, 
  status_id AS CurrState
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Customer_Details
ON(Orders.customer_id = Customer_Details.id)
INNER JOIN Order_Tracking
ON(Orders.id = Order_Tracking.order_id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, MAX(id) id FROM Order_Tracking GROUP BY order_id) LastOrderTracking
ON (Order_Tracking.id = LastOrderTracking.id)
WHERE status_id = 1
ORDER BY Orders.order_number;
```

You may take a look on a live [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf1c/12) and see how many filesort operations are present in execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I have tested on another page which does not use DISTINCT and the SQL has now been running for 480 seconds (data provided from MySQL runtime information). I cannot see how the SQLs could be causing this issue as they returned data after 5/6 seconds on the old server. `SELECT o.id, o.order_number AS OrderNumber, (

SELECT status_id
FROM Order_Tracking
WHERE order_id = o.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
)CurrState
FROM Orders o
WHERE (

SELECT status_id
FROM Order_Tracking
WHERE order_id = o.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
)
IN ( 1, 2, 3, 7, 10 )`

Comment: As a further note, just remembered that this issue is exactly the same issues when we attempted to put one of our webapps onto localhost in the office (WampServer), It has got to be a server setting or caching setting as the code/SQLs haven't changed.

Comment: Please take a look on updated answer and compare executions plans. This shows that you have problems with query optimization.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it is currently not viable to alter all SQLs - we are talking hundreds if not thousands. Granted, we know that the SQLs are far from optimized, however they were working on the old server and now are not working on new server (with much higher spec). As such the Webapps are none functional. Long term plan is to alter SQLs which we have already begun, however short term plan is to get server configs setup correctly - any help with these settings would be appreciated (I am well out of my comfort zone!).

Comment: Sure it doesn't make sense to optimize all the SQL code. But you can determine the most critical and slowest queries based on slow query log and optimize only them. Initially you will be in need to invest in refactoring but later this will brings you benefits when it will be possible to save money on hosting.

Comment: Okay, cool - a good point. I just ran the above mentioned SQL on our old server and a result was returned back in 2.5 seconds. I then ran it on the new server and a result still has not been returned (after 20 minutes) + MySQL server crashed and required a restart, plus the CPU usage was jumping all over the place. Makes me think the old server was better than the new one (even though spec 4GB RAM vs 28GB RAM & 4 CPUs vs 12 CPUs).